# Optimizing Loss Function for Speed in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, loss-function

I'm working on a unet model for image inpainting. In order to successfully train the model I've had to create a custom loss function. However, this loss function is extremely slow when compared to the standard loss functions. Is there any way that this loss function can be optimized? The portion that's slow is MSGMS calculation portion. Before I introduced this loss component, all operations were using tensor cores on my nvidia 2070 super. I can see in the TF profiler that the most time consuming operations with this loss component aren't using tensor cores (see image).

[image]

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio
import tensorflow_addons as tfa


def tf_median_blur(filter_shape):
    def median_filter2d(image):
        return tfa.image.median_filter2d(
            image, filter_shape=filter_shape, padding='REFLECT'
        )

    return median_filter2d


def gms(x_true, y_pred, c=0.0026):
    x = tf.reduce_mean(x_true, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    y = tf.reduce_mean(y_pred, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    g_true = tfio.experimental.filter.prewitt(tf_median_blur((3, 3))(x))
    g_pred = tfio.experimental.filter.prewitt(tf_median_blur((3, 3))(y))
    g_map = (2 * g_true * g_pred + c) / (g_true ** 2 + g_pred ** 2 + c)
    gms_loss = 1 - tf.reduce_mean(g_map)
    return gms_loss


def msgms(x_true, y_pred):
    total_loss = gms(x_true, y_pred)
    for _ in range(3):
        x_true = tf.nn.avg_pool2d(x_true, ksize=2, strides=2, padding='SAME')
        y_pred = tf.nn.avg_pool2d(y_pred, ksize=2, strides=2, padding='SAME')
        total_loss += gms(x_true, y_pred)

    return total_loss / 4

def CustomLossFunc(y_true, y_pred, gamma=1, alpha=1, beta=1):
    y_true = tf.cast(y_true, dtype=tf.float32)
    y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, dtype=tf.float32)
    l2_loss = tf.losses.Huber()(y_true, y_pred)
    gms_loss = msgms(y_true, y_pred)
    ssim_loss = SSIMLoss(y_true, y_pred)
#     tf.print('\n', 'l2_loss: ', l2_loss, ' gms_loss: ', gms_loss, ' ssim_loss: ', ssim_loss)
    loss = (
        gamma * l2_loss 
        + alpha * gms_loss
        + beta * ssim_loss
    )
    return loss

model.compile(
    optimizer=optimizer, 
#     loss=simple_diff
#     loss=SSIMLoss
#     loss=tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_logarithmic_error
#     loss=MSE,
    loss=CustomLossFunc
)
```

Comment: Have you tried [compiling your function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function)?

Comment: @dankal444 yes, it doesn't have an affect on the speed. I believe this is because it's the TopKV2 operation in the GPU that is slow